# How do I select column by looping strings in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector list:

`indieVars <- c("COL1","COL2","COL3")`

I want to run this code

```
for(indieVar in indieVars){
  myDataFrame$indieVar
}
```

Only problem is the loop thinks it's looking for a column in `myDataFrame` called `indieVar`. I want it to look for the column name represented by `indieVar`. How do I do this?

Comment: Use `[` or `[[` depending on what you want.

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair Where would I put that?

Comment: `$` means exact match, that's why your loop won't work. Try `myDataFrame[indieVar]`